# How do you cause a program to wait for a set amount of time?

Tags: java, wait

How do you make a program that waits for 3 seconds?
I've heard about this:

```
obj.wait()
```

But I'm just wondering about the syntax and what to import?

Comment: `obj.wait()` is to wait until another thread calls `notify()`.  Nothing directly to do with "waiting for X amount of time".

Answer (score 1):

This will put your code to sleep for 3 seconds:

```
try{
Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
 Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `

> java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

`and the you can run:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
```